# Is there any way to print out all GC Details in .NET 7.0?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I deployed my applications in kubernetes. some of the service keep getting OOM Killed. I've tried to change GC Variables many times, including GC Heap Count & GC Heap Limit using environment variables. I even upgrade my nodes to have higher memory. But the issue persist. Is there a way to Print Out all GC Details. I wonder .NET really pick up my environment variables when I set it. something like JAVA PrintGCDetails will be helpful to help me inspect and debug my issue. Is there anything similar in .NET?

Answer (score 3):

There is an `GC Class` in .Net that allows you to get needed information about Garbage Collector.

To check if you correctly set the variables, you could use the `GetConfigurationVariables()` method:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> configurationVariables = GC.GetConfigurationVariables();
```

The default result is here, including the **HeapCount** and **Limits**:

[image: GC variables results]

There are much more abilities to interact with GC you can find by the **[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc?view=net-7.0)**.

In case if you have correctly set variables and you are still facing the same problem, you are able to monitor your memory in debugging mode by using the **Diagnostic Tools** window in Visual Studio for instance:

[image: Diagnostic Tools]

You might also be interested in the next [**tool**](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/main/documentation/design-docs/dotnet-tools.md), allowing you to get some details about your app memory during the run-time.